# Python function where the input changes with the key in a dict

Tags: python, function, dictionary, input

So im trying to make a function in python that takes the user input and sends it in an if-loop but the hard part is that it should change the output to a certain answer for every chapter in my dict.
Imagine you have a text adventure with a question with 2 answers. One of these answers gets you to the next chapter (whatever chapter is next) and the other answers gives you a certain death text (depending on what chapter you are in).

I know how to write the loop but i have no idea how to change the output for every chapter (without creating a new func every time).

```
def Eingabe_loop(Eingabe):
    if Eingabe == 1:
        pass # should redirect to next Chapter (whatever chapter is next)
    elif Eingabe == 2:
        pass # should redirect to whatever chapters death text (depending on chapter we are in)
    elif Eingabe == 'i':
        Inv()
    elif Eingabe == 's':
        Status()
    else:
        print('Wrong input!')
```

Eingabe means Input in german :)
1 and 2 are the questions and i and s are always available

```
    },
    'Chapter_1': 
    {
     'Main': 'Chapter_1',
     'Main_Q1': ['Q1', 'Q2'],
    },
    'Chapter_2':
    {
     'Main': 'Chapter_2',
     'Main_Q1': ['Q1', 'Q2'],
     'Sub': 'Chapter_2_Sub',
     'Sub_Q1': ['Q1', 'Q2']
    }
```

This is a part of my dict with the 1st chapter and the 1st block of questions that should redirect you to chapter 2 or kill you. The 1st Key of the dict is called 'Start' btw

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am picturing you are looking for. So the for loop will determine what chapter you are and the list of chapterDeathText, you can define all the death texts you want. you can pass in the death text and what chapter you are into a function and do you don't need to keep redefining it.

```
def Eingabe_loop(Eingabe, chapter):
    if Eingabe == str(1):
        pass # should redirect to next Chapter (whatever chapter is next)
    elif Eingabe == str(2):
       print (chapter)
    #elif Eingabe == 'i':
    #    Inv()
    #elif Eingabe == 's':
    #    Status()
    else:
        print('Wrong input!')


chapterDeathText = ['text1. quick death', 'text2.sad death', 'text3..death']

for x in range(3): # range of chapters
    response = input('Whats your answer?\n')
    Eingabe_loop(response, chapterDeathText[x])
```

Additionally, you could if you dont want '1' to always be the correct answer you could define them in the same way of a list and past in that index value.

EDIT:

```
def Eingabe_loop(Eingabe, chapter):
    if Eingabe == 1:
        pass # should redirect to next Chapter (whatever chapter is next)
    elif Eingabe == 2:
        deathPrompts(chapter)
    elif Eingabe == 'i':
        Inv()
    elif Eingabe == 's':
        Status()
    else:
        print('Wrong input!')

def deathPrompts(chapter):
    if chapter == 0:
        print('first death')
    elif chapter == 1:
        print('2nd death')
    # ...


for x in range(3): # range of chapters
    Eingabe_loop(Eingabe, x)
```

Comment: Thanks @user50930 for the quick answer but how am i going to know what chapter is next (where i need to redirect to) and i would use full sentences for my deaths they cant fit in this list. Because i am using a dict to print my text adventure in the console my input is a pre-defined variable called 'Eingabe' that is why the for loop has Eingabe in it so response = input wouldnt work.

Comment: see the bottom part of what I added, if thats the case you could just have death prompts be its own function. It determines what chapter its on by what iteration of the loop. Aka first iteration is chapter1, so you can pass the index of the loop. @IsItMe